# Lowering VCE(sat) for analog transistor switch

Tags: transistors, switches, programmable-logic

I've been wanting to build a primitive programmable logic device using mainly bipolar transistors.

One of the defining characteristics of a PLD is the ability to select what inputs get passed through to the AND array, so I think some sort of externally controlled transmission switch would be of course a necessity.

I am of course familiar with the workings of high-side and low-side switches and inverters. I've found while searching the web some examples of transmission switches that can pass or reject an input signal. The ones I found used an NPN transistor to drive either the base of PNP transistor or the gate of  JFET. In both cases, as showcased below it would be understandable to want to decrease VCE(sat) of the bipolar transistors.

[image: Figure 5-7 JFET switch control circuit]
<sub>Image source: [Siliconix Inc - Designing With Field Effect Transistors (published by McGraw-Hill, from bitsavers.org)](http://www.bitsavers.org/components/siliconix/Designing_With_Field_Effect_Transistors_1981.pdf)</sub>

[image: Figure 3. Load Switch − Seat Warmer]
<sub>Image source: [OnSemi - TND6093/D Low VCE(sat) BJT's in Automotive Applications](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/tnd6093-d.pdf)</sub>

Most transistor that I have in my possession have a typical VCE(sat) of about 0.2 to 0.4V, which I find to be quite high. I am aware of the existence of low-VCE(sat) PNP transistors, but would prefer to use what I already have.

So, in short I would like to know:

1. If there are any techniques for considerably decreasing VCE(sat)?
2. Could these techniques be applied to both NPN and PNP transistors?

Comment: Some BJTs will have a lower Vce(sat) when the collector is used as the emitter and visa versa. You could test it with your batch. The base current will need to be higher. Most BJTs aren't symmetrical now (but a lifetime ago there were some symmetrical BJTs.)

Comment: I've seen this discussed previously, using the BJT in the reverse active region for lower VCE(sat). I have used this in a circuit before, but would like to restrict myself to the usual operating regions.

Comment: @periblepsis you should put it as an answer.

Comment: @RohatKılıç It appears Virgil isn't interested in that approach. Besides, it's only something I've played at a few times and I've not spent the personal time needed to validate the idea with accessible parts. (Simulator is one thing. Reality sometimes another.) And I especially don't care to write when the answer explicitly isn't wanted.

Comment: @periblepsis I appreciate you for taking the time to entertain my question. I would like to refrain from working in the reverse active region mainly because I'm concerned about the reverse breakdown voltage of the Base Emitter junction. I intend to use the analog switch for large 5V logic signals. I am looking for something similar to antisaturation diodes or baker clamps like those used  for the usual bipolar transistor switches.

Comment: @Virgil_Tibbs I'm just letting Rohat know why I'm not writing. You have good reasons.